# How to dynamically pull to ground USB D+/-

Tags: usb, usb-device

I have two separate electronics parts linked together via USB D+, D- and GND only (no VBUS).

On the second circuitry (part B), I have [FAN3989-D](https://www.onsemi.com/products/isolation-protection-devices/voltage-protection/fan3989) ([pdf](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FAN3989-D.pdf)). VBAT=4.2V is on all the time.

On the first circuitry (part A), I want to implement a logic to control D+ and D-.

[image]

What should I build so that FLAG1 is high when S1 is on and FLAG1 is low when S1 is open? I guess that I want to short D+ and D- when S1 is on. How could I do that?

Comment: "when S1 is on (D+ and D- would be shorted I guess)"- what do you mean "you guess"? Ether you know (or specify) what D+ and D- should be if S1=on, or you don't design the whole thing.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: For reference `The FAN3989 sets the FLAG1 pin to logic HIGH or LOW as an indicator to the system controller that a standard USB device or a charger is connected to the USB port.`

Answer (score 1):

As described by the FAN3989 data sheet, FLAG1 high means:

> If a charger is plugged into the USB port (D+ and D- shorted), the voltage divider of 1M and 5M put a voltage of 2.3V on the D+D- inputs and flag1 is HIGH, indicating a charger is connected to port.

While FLAG1 low means:

> If the USB port is connected to a standard USB device, the D+ input is pulled up to VDD and is in parallel with the 1.5KΩ on a USB transceiver with a parallel R value of 1.497KΩ. The D- input is connected to a 15KΩ pull-down by the USB device and in parallel with 5MΩ with a parallel R value of 14.955KΩ. This condition forces flag1 LOW. If D+ and D- are open (floating), D+ is pulled to VDD and D- floats LOW, which forces flag1 LOW.

So if you have a standard USB device and not a USB Charger, then **Flag1 will always be low** regardless if the usb device is connected or if the usb device is unconnected. *It's unlikely you can modify the connection without interfering with the USB connection. The FAN3989 is not meant to flag between standard device and unconnected.*

Assuming you have a usb charger plugged in, you will need to implement a **usb switch** between the device and the FAN3989. The input of which would be tied into VUSB/5V after the S1 switch. This would disconnect the D+ and D- lines, leaving them floating, so that the FLAG1 goes low.

If you have a usb transceiver, then look at page 8 of the data sheet for how it works.

Comment: Thanks for help. it would have been better if you could have used "PartA" and "PartB" in your explanations but I think that i get your point. Let's say that I put TPS2514 in Part A with the pin IN linked to S1. My understanding is that it's going to dependent what is on the right of "PartB". There is a USB controller (BCP compliant) but it can be off. If it is, I don't think that FLAG1 is going to go high. That's the core of my question

Comment: If I put in PartA two mosfets in opposite direction to link D+ and D-, both gates of the mosfets linked to S1, am I going to see a toggle of FLAG1 depending of the status of S1? The idea is that if S1 is on, the mosfets "short" D+ and D- while if S1 is off, D+ and D- are opened/floating.